# Linksys WRT54GS QoS on wired and wireless

Tags: wrt54g

I am going to have two routers set up as described in part 2 [here](http://www.northshore-it.com/tips/how-tos/cascade_linksys/). My main router (connected to cable modem) is a Linksys WRT54GS running Linksys firmware.

I want my 'private' network (anything connected to second router) to have priority over and wireless devices connected to the main router (the WRT54GS). Is this possible, and how do I do this?

For reference, here's what my [QoS configuration page](http://screenshots.portforward.com/Linksys/WRT54GS/QoS.jpg) looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two options for QoS setup with that config page is to prioritize anything from the MAC address of the Private router or prioritize the port the Private router is on. Either of these will work, I'm just not sure specifically with Linksys if there is any efficiency difference between the two options.

Comment: Alright, so if I prioritize my private router, does that automatically mean that anything else has a lower priority? (I know the logical answer is yes, but was just wondering if a lower priority must be explicit or it is implied if I set the private router as high priority)

Comment: relative to the private router, yes. It elevates the priority on the private router above everything else that passes through the public router. You could specify a lower priority for other devices on the public router and that would put them below the normal priority. There are basically 3 steps that router allows, high (specified), normal (not specified), low (specified). Basically, you can set something to be the highest or the lowest, but unspecified devices just run at normal priority.

Comment: Would QoS enable me to have higher speeds on my private router compared to public? For example, if you are downloading a file on each router, would be speeds be something like 70/30 or does QoS just enable the private router to have a higher ping or something?

Comment: QoS just means that if two packets come in at the same time, if one has a higher priority tag on it, it goes through first. It will not inherently increase or decrease latency - in other words, everything will remain at normal speeds, but if traffic from the private router hits the public router at the same time traffic from the public network does, it will simply process the traffic from the private network first.

Comment: So is there any better strategy if I want to maintain higher speeds on the private router?

Comment: There is no need to do anything further, it will have priority, it will always get its traffic out first. It will maintain the highest speed the link is capable of, it will not be slowed down by traffic on the public network as it's traffic will be processed first.

Comment: I should point out though, that the circuit as a whole may still slow down if the combined traffic over-utilizes it. QoS will only go as far as your router, meaning that once the traffic hits the first hop, all bets are off and your ISP will see it all as one big mesh of packets taking up X amount of bandwidth. So you will still have your normal circuit cap. If you want to split circuit bandwidth between the two networks, you would have to implement a FAR more complex system. The downside is, if you do this, you will never get 100% on either network, it will need to remain split.